# Layer Navigation on attribute

Tags: layer

I want to display **color,fabric,size,discount,Brand search/Filter options** in **products page**.

So customer can search a tshirt  like color-Blue,Fabric-Cotton,Size-XL,Discount 50-60%,Brand-Pepe.

How to do from Admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to enable Magento Layered Navigation for it. To enable it, follow below steps:

**STEP 1**

1) Goto Category from `Products >> Categories(Magento 2)` and click on the category of your choice.

2) Select the desired category and Goto `Display Settings`

3) Make `Anchor = YES` and save the changes.

This will make your selected category show layered navigation on frontend. You can go to that particular category and check from frontend.

**STEP 2**

To make any attribute eligible to be displayed in layered navigation, you need to ensure that attribute is set allowed to display in layered navigation as yes. To do so follow below steps:

1) Goto `Stores >> Attributes >> Product Attributes`

2) Select the attribute which you want to display in filter on frontend. We are considering `color` for example.

3) After going on detail page of `color` attribute, Goto `storefront properties` tab and select `Use in Layered Navigation` as `Fiterable(with results)` or `Fiterable(no results)` as per your preferences.

4) Save the changes and perform reindex.

I am assuming you are using Magento 2.x for your project. If its Magento 1.x, then the steps remains same only the method to reach the particular option will change.

Hope it helps.